# React: Find modules, not used

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I came into a team that had already started a React team.  The installation takes 30 minute into the cloud because of all the dependencies in node_module.   When I look in this folder, there are 1084 folders.   I'm pretty sure there are a lot of stuff here that is never touched, but may also be in the package.json.   In attempted to clean up and speed up the installation process, is there any automated way to find out if our project actually needs it, without removing one item at a time?

Comment: You could make a program the get every package of the `package.json` and search in the project if it's being imported or not. This way you can know which are being used or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck to clean you package.json

2) delete node_modules and reinstall everything

Comment: Based on reading this, depcheck highlights unused dependencies in the package.json, which would work perfectly.   However, I work for a bank that blocks all installation and has their own repository of approved extensions.   depcheck isn't one of them.   :(   but I'll give you credit for it as that is the answer that would work.

Comment: @Switch why do you need to run it on production? Run in it locally, clean the package.json and commit the changes.

Comment: I never said anything about production.  Every person works on VDIs and they block us from installing anything locally.   This includes “npm i depcheck” if its not in the company repository.